# How to identify variables of a dataset?

Tags: variable

I have a dataset of the annual sales of a bakery and I'm confused about how many variables it has.

Is it the number of products or the number of years? Can someone help me out?

[image]

Comment: It's two variables: year and product, you can also consider "count" a third variable if you want.

Comment: "Variable" is a concept in mathematics and statistics but not for datasets.  The latter is concerned about "columns" or "fields" in a *table* (more formally known as a *relation*).  There is not necessarily a one-to-one correspondence between a statistical variable and a column in a rectangular array like this one.  Furthermore, there is a different concept of "variable" in computing that applies to the *internal representation* of data in a computer model.  Thus, your question has multiple different answers -- beware!

Answer (score 3):

##### You have three "variables" in this table: product, year and sales-count

As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/) points out in the comments, computational representation of data in tables often uses the terminology of "columns" or "fields" rather than variables, and there are sometimes interpretive issues in deciding what the variables are for a statistical representation of the problem.  Notwithstanding this caveat, I think we are on safe ground here in identifying that there are three variables of interest here: product, year, and sales-count.

At present, your data is presented in "wide form", shown as a two-dimensional matrix of sales counts, indexed by the two other variables (product and year) as row and column names.  (This is a form we often call a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).)  When we model data using statistical models, we would generally convert this data into "long form" for the three variables, which would be a table with 3 columns with 30 rows --- one row showing the sales-count for each combination of product and year.

Answer (score 1):

This could be argued to have seven variables, where six come from the six foods, and one comes from the year. In that sense, each value in the box can be identified by the type of food and the year.

Or it could be three variables: one variable is the type of food, one variable is the year, and one variable is the amount produced of a good in a year.

Both of these are reasonable, and it is a judgment call for which could be best in a given setting. Indeed, even this contingency table could make sense in some settings.

If you find it confusing to interpret a table like this, you might be interested in the Tidyverse and “tidy” data frames. The second of the two ideas I wrote is most aligned with being tidy, though there can be advantages to various ways of representing the data.

Answer (score -1):

It has two variables: product and year. The dataset is this:

[image]

A dataset like this is usually made to store individual sales. The table you drew is called 'Contingency table' and it records the tally of records with a given combination of variables. The first cell (550) says that there are 550 records with Product='Loaf' and Year='2018', the second cell says that there are 583 records with Product='Loaf' and Year='2019', and so on.

From the contingency table you can make a table with three variables: product, year and sales.

[image]

A dataset like this is usually made to record the summary of sales at the end of each year.